# android setting ontouchlistener on linearlayout does not work

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I am new to android and I'm trying to detect sliding events. If I add my listener to a webview or textview it works perfectly fine:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebview);        
myWebView.setOnTouchListener(myListener);
```

However if I create a linearlayout with some items in it and then try to add my listener nohing happens:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
ll.setOnTouchListener(myListener);
```

As far as I know both WebView and LinearLayout extend the View class so setOnTouchListener should work on both of them just fine. My question is how do I get it working on my linear layout view? I tried to set the listener for all children of the layout separately, but it's not what I'm looking for. If, for example, this is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then sliding event will be detected if I slide the actual chidlren of the layout, i.e. my radio buttons or spinners. But if I slide on the empty space of the layout nothing happens

Any help and pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this listener

```
LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);


            l.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("Touch","Sample x"+arg1.getX());
                    Log.i("Touch","Sample x"+arg1.getY());
                    return true;
                }
            });
```